# Perl return scalar value or first element if it's array in one line

Tags: perl

`$scalar = function();`

if function return scalar it is ok, but if return array i need to assign first element from array. how to write it in Perl in one line?

edit:
Is it possible without variable like this:

```
call_another_func(function());
```

Comment: array is a type of variable, never a type of value: subs cannot return an array.  they can return a list or a reference to an array.

Comment: @ysth yes, but... `return wantarray?...`

Comment: unfortunately misnamed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in parens if it returns list of elements,

```
my ($scalar) = function();
```

same thing, taking first list element,

```
my $scalar = (function())[0];
```

or dereference if it returns array reference,

```
my ($scalar) = @{ function() };
```

Comment: or explicitly slice it (often this provides the best documentation of what's happening): `my $scalar = (function())[0];`

Comment: @ysth tnx for comment, although I'm not fan of it.

Comment: good defensive code if you work with people who will say "oh, unnecessary parentheses, I'll remove them", not "oh, a list assignment".

Comment: @ysth correct, I've seen that once by "senior" perl dev.

Answer (score 1):

Subs can't return a arrays. They can only return a list of zero or more scalars. The following will pass the first scalars returned by `function` to `call_another_func` as an argument:

```
call_another_func( ( function() )[0] );
```